# Laravel - set meta tag dynamically with @section

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i would like implement facebook share button function whereby it will capture the meta tags information during user hit the share button.

I've a head.blade.php that include some meta tag to be captured. Example

```
<meta property="og:url" content="@yield('facebook_share_url')">
<meta property="og:image" content="@yield('facebook_share_image')">
<meta property="og:description" content="@yield('facebook_share_description')">
```

And i have a default.blade.php.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    @include('includes.head')
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <header class="row">
        @include('includes.header')
    </header>

    <div id="main" class="row">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</div>

@include('includes.footer')
</body>
</html>
```

So when i browse to some url says www.example.com/details, the default.blade.php will yield the content from this details.blade. And at this moment i would like to change the facebook meta tag properties, so i did something like below in details page.

```
@section('facebook_share_image', 'This is a description')
@section('facebook_share_description', 'This is an individual page title')
```

The code work fine but i would like to render it from my view data. Something like `@section('facebook_share_description', {{ $data->description }})`

but when i check my meta tag, it gives me nothing. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: **head.blade.php** contains only the meta tags or something else as well ?

Comment: meta tags and some other css/ javascript link..
example <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you want or what you are looking for, but why not try placing the `meta` tags in the **default.blade.php** only instead of placing it in a partial.

For example, insert in `head` tag of default.blade.php:

```
@yield('facebook_meta')
```

**view_file.blade.php**

```
@section('facebook_meta')
    <meta property="og:url" content="Place your data here">
    <meta property="og:image" content="Place your data here">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Place your data here">
@endsection
```

The above approach works much better, according to me.

Maybe this can help you out.

Comment: is this really an effective solution? did that work @Darren Lau